# Vertical image slider in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have create a bootstrap template take a look on the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqryL7ra/).

In web browser normal size it looks fine but when I resize my browser the design go bad.

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin template -->
<div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
</div>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-N9L7ykby8so/VLYAjhc3N1I/AAAAAAAAE_E/K6n32KF3VA4/s1600/1.png" /></div>
   <div class="col-xs-8" id="left">
    
      <h2> Captain America</h2>
      
      <!-- item list -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><a href="">Item heading</a></div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
        Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
        dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
        Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</p>
          <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
              Quisque mauris augue, 
          </p>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><a href="">Item heading</a></div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
        Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
        dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
        Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
         </p>
          <p> Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
        dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
        Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</p>
      
          <p>
              Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
              dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
              Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
          </p>
      
         

          <hr>
     
      
      
        
      <p>
      <a href="http://bootply.com" target="_ext" class="center-block btn btn-primary">More Bootstrap Snippets on Bootply</a>
      </p>
        
        

    </div>
 
    
  </div>
</div>
```

and I also want a fade slider on the place of image can its possible in `class="col-xs-4"` class.

Comment: y you r thinkinking slider is not possible :) .. your alignment get failure place wrapper .. use bootstrap wrapper class..

Comment: @Sarath i mean to say in `class="col-xs-4"`

Comment: yes definitely you can..@Gitz

Comment: then my next by default question is `HOW` ? Without spoiling design  @Sarath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this you need..? try zoom it

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- begin template -->
<div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top container">
 <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
   <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
               
              <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-N9L7ykby8so/VLYAjhc3N1I/AAAAAAAAE_E/K6n32KF3VA4/s1600/1.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-N9L7ykby8so/VLYAjhc3N1I/AAAAAAAAE_E/K6n32KF3VA4/s1600/1.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
       
  <script> $('.carousel').carousel(); </script>
    <!--<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-N9L7ykby8so/VLYAjhc3N1I/AAAAAAAAE_E/K6n32KF3VA4/s1600/1.png" />  -->
 </div>
   <div class="col-xs-8" id="left">
    
      <h2> Captain America</h2>
      
      <!-- item list -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><a href="">Item heading</a></div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
        Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
        dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
        Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</p>
          <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
              Quisque mauris augue, 
          </p>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><a href="">Item heading</a></div>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
        Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
        dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
        Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
         </p>
          <p> Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
        dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
        Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</p>
      
          <p>
              Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
              dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
              Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
          </p>
      
          <hr>
      <p>
      <a href="http://bootply.com" target="_ext" class="center-block btn btn-primary">More Bootstrap Snippets on Bootply</a>
      </p>
  </div>
 </div> <!-- Container -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much buddy really appreciate your answer :)

Comment: make margin-top: 52px; for class="col-xs-4" .. it looks great..:)